Dummit and Foote, Possible Mistake in Cyclotomic Fields Section
Question
I am having trouble understanding the italicized part in the following excerpt from page 598 of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd ed. In this text, we have $\zeta_n = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$.

Suppose that $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ is the decomposition of $n$ into distinct prime powers. Since $\zeta_n^{p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}}$ is a primitive $p_1^{a_1}$-th root of unity, the field $K_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p_1^{a_1}})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Similarly, each of the fields $K_i = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p_i^{a_i}}), i=1, 2, ..., k$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. The composite of the fields contains the product $\zeta_{p_1^{a_1}}\zeta_{p_2^{a_2}}\cdots\zeta_{p_k^{a^k}}$, which is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, hence the composite field is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Since the extension degrees $[K_i:\mathbb{Q}]$ equal $\phi(p_i^{a_i}), i=1, 2, ..., k$ and $\phi(n)=\phi(p_1^{a_1})\phi(p_2^{a_2})\cdots\phi(p_k^{a_k})$, the degree of the composite of the fields $K_i$ is precisely the product of the degrees of the $K_i$. It follows from Proposition 21 (and a simple induction from the two fields considered in the proposition to the $k$ fields here) that the inersection of all these fields is precisely $\mathbb{Q}$.

We have

Proposition 21 Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be Galois extensions of a field $F$. Then
(1) The intersection $K_1 \cap K_2$ is Galois over $F$. (2) The composite $K_1K_2$ is Galois over $F$. The Galois group is isomorphic to the subgroup $$H = \{(\sigma, \tau)\ |\  \sigma|_{K_1 \cap K_2} = \tau|_{K_1 \cap K_2}\}$$ of the direct product $\mathrm{Gal}(K_1/F) \times \mathrm{Gal}(K_2/F)$ consisting of elements whose restrictions to the intersection $K_1 \cap K_2$ are equal.

My thoughts
Instead of using Proposition 21, it seems the authors were reasoning that since the degree of the composite is already equal to the product of the constituent fields' degrees, by a generalization of Corollary 20 stated below (namely the numerator would be product of all the $[K_i:F]$'s and the denominator would be $[\cap_{i=1}^{k}K_i:F]$), the constituent fields intersect only in the rationals.

Corollary 20 Suppose $K/F$ is a Galois extension and $F'/F$ is any finite extension. Then $$[KF':F] = \frac{[K:F][F':F]}{[K\cap F': F]}.$$

However, I am having difficulty proving this "simple induction", and I am beginning to suspect that it is false.
I think I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

I guess the point is really to take a corollary like the following (which you can get from either Corollary 20 or from Proposition 21):

Corollary 1: If $K,K'$ are Galois extensions of $F$ and $[KK':F]=[K:F][K':F]$, then $K\cap K'=F$.

This statement you can induct on to get the following:

Corollary 2: If $K_1,\dots,K_n$ are Galois extensions of $F$ and $[K_1\cdots K_n:F]=\prod_{i=1}^n[K_i:F]$ then $K_1\cap\cdots\cap K_n=F$.

Proof of Corollary 2: Assuming the equality, we find
$$[K_1\cdots K_{n-1}:F][K_n:F]\geqslant[K_1\cdots K_{n-1}K_n:F]=\prod_{i=1}^n [K_i:F]=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}[K_i:F]\right)[K_n:F]\geqslant[K_1\cdots K_{n-1}:F][K_n:F].$$
As a result these are all equalities, so as a result $K_1,\dots,K_{n-1}$ satisfy the inductive hypothesis.

Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. +1
